# Is there a css selector that selects an attribute of an element equals to its parent's attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I'm using this kind of technique to filter the items according to its parent's `data-current` attribute:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => ul.setAttribute('data-current', target.value));
```

```css
ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul[data-current='vegetable'] li[data-category='vegetable'],
ul[data-current='fruit'] li[data-category='fruit'],
ul[data-current='dessert'] li[data-category='dessert'],
ul[data-current='misc'] li[data-category='misc'],
ul[data-current='all'] li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
  <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
  <option value="dessert">Dessert</option>
  <option value="misc">Misc</option>
</select>

<ul data-current="all">
  <li data-category="vegetable">Tomato</li>
  <li data-category="vegetable">Cucumber</li>
  <li data-category="vegetable">Eggplant</li>
  <li data-category="fruit">Apple</li>
  <li data-category="fruit">Banana</li>
  <li data-category="fruit">Orange</li>
  <li data-category="dessert">Cake</li>
  <li data-category="dessert">Chocolate</li>
  <li data-category="misc">Beef Jerky</li>
</ul>
```

It works fine by now, but as you can see the selectors are getting heavier while the `data-category` populates. Also, it would be impossible if the categories are dynamic.

Is there a selector like this, that `$1` matches the previous string?

```css
ul[data-current=/(.*)/] li[data-category=$1] {
  display: block;
}
```

What would be a better idea to achieve this kind of filter feature?

I don't really like manually hiding/showing each element using javascript.

Comment: Impossible with CSS (unless you're gonna manually add a setting for each possible value)

Comment: So wish we have this feature in CSS, that we can achieve so much more without javascript.

Comment: Well CSS is supposed to be kept simple, fast and easy to interpret. What you're suggesting is pretty complicated IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

When designing languages, there's often a trade-off between power and simplicity, and CSS tends to favour simplicity. Even features like sibling selectors and attribute selectors weren't introduced until version 2.

What you describe may *occasionally* be useful, but probably 99% of developers aren't going to see a need for it. No current version of CSS provides an ability to do this, and I can't see any future version of CSS allowing it either, unless they add some sort of generic way to embed XPath or Javascript into selectors. (And those ideas are not outside the realms of possibility.)

It is, however, pretty easy to implement in Javascript. I'm using jQuery in the following example, but doing it without jQuery isn't hard either...

```
function updateLists ( node ) {
  node.find('ul[data-current]').each( function ( ix, e ) {
    var val  = e.getAttribute('data-current');
    var list = jQuery( e );
    list.find( '.current-category' ).removeClass( 'current-category' );
    list.find( 'li[data-category=' + val + ']' ).addClass( 'current-category' );
  } );
}

// Call updateLists whenever the category gets changed
updateLists( jQuery( document.body ) );
```

```
ul[data-current] > li {
  display: none;
}

ul[data-current] > li.current-category {
  display: block;
}
```